# Inconsistent accesibility: property type is less accesible than property

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a windows forms application in C#. The error i'm getting is in the title.

I'm quite new to C# so if i'm asking something stupid please excuse me since I can't find a similar situation from which I can find the answer. In the below class i'm getting the error.

Kassaregistratiesysteem.cs:

```
public class Kassaregistatiesysteem
{
    private string Naam { get; set; }
    private List<Medewerker> medewerkers;

    public Kassaregistatiesysteem(string naam)
    {
        this.Naam = naam;

        // Maak lijsten aan
        medewerkers = new List<Medewerker>();

        // Lees alles in
    }

    // Read-only properties
    public List<Medewerker> Medewerkers { get { return this.medewerkers; } } // <-- This is where the error occurs


    private void LeesMedewerkers()
    {
        Medewerker medewerker1 = new Medewerker(1, "Graham", "Neal", "bediening", "Graham", "0000");
        medewerkers.Add(medewerker1);
    }
}
```

In the below class I would like to use the list

login.cs

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    Kassaregistatiesysteem systeem = new Kassaregistatiesysteem("MayaMaya");
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnInloggen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = tbxUsername.Text;
        string pincode = tbxPincode.Text;

        foreach (Medewerker m in systeem.Medewerkers)
        {
            if (m.Username == username && m.Pincode == pincode)
            {
                // Login
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                Hide();
                menu.ShowDialog();
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not only want the answer but why this error occurs so I know what is going wrong.

If I haven't asked my question the right way please do not judge me and help me learn what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Most likely Medewerker is internal ( public List<Medewerker> Medewerkers). You can't have public property of not-publit type

Comment: Make sure your class `Medewerker` is public.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Thanks @Habib for the quick answer. I searched it in the wrong two classes of the three

Comment: Habib you were totally right.